# Need feedback on my internship experience

Tags: management, recruitment, internship, project-management

I am an intern as data consultant, I am experimenting a visualization software for the company i'm working for during 6 months.
I started off with another subject and on my very first day, the manager and project lead told me there is a change in my mission, basically I was supposed to evaluate many software BI tools but ended up with only one to use.

I spent the first week setting up my environment and doing welcome meetings and learning about this tool, exploring a huge database..etc

I would be surprised how other interns had clear vision about what they were doing but no me. My supposed to be mentor/manager had a lot of work and I was told he will not assist me during the first month. Because I had previous experience working as a software engineer for 2 years I was able to identify some tasks and would assign them to myself just so I don't end up sitting doing nothing. So I have explored the database, made a dashboard with many charts and even done extra than some charts that were asked from me to deliver.

From time to time I would have questions about some tables in the database and would turn to the architects of the team and project lead but they were very busy and would not provide valuable answers, I ended up just doing all I could to figure things out and understand the meaning behind some tables.

More context, my original diploma won't allow me to apply in France for a job directly. This is why I applied for a master's degree in France and need to pass an internship to validate my master's year.
I moved to France for an international master's degree in AI and Data and there were not many internships in the city where I am based so I applied for this one that seemed like a data analyst internship but so far it's been discouraging and very boring...

My question is is it common to do this in an internship of a well established company?
I started regretting this career switch, coming from a CS master's degree and having 2 years of experience as software engineers I wanted to become a data engineer because I'm passionate about data, programming and solving problems, do you think I did a bad choice?

Comment: Maybe it's a translation issue, but why would you need an internship when you have a masters degree and 2 years experience in development? I mean it's not exactly data science or AI, but it sure seems leaps and bounds beyond an internship. But again, maybe it just doesn't translate to what our labor market is used to doing here and I just don't get it.

Comment: my bad, my original diploma won't allow me to apply in France for a job directly. This is why I applied for a master's degree in France and need to pass an internship to validate my master's year

Comment: How does a college degree limit your ability to work in France?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is is it common to do this in an internship of a well established company?

No usually they're better organised than that. But things do fall through the cracks sometimes.